# Using access token to offline access (for background processes)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I want to write a Facebook Application that checks a user defined RSS feed periodically and import new items to users'/pages' wall(I know, there are similar apps). But I couldn't find an useful manual for authenticating for background processes. I mean, you know, I must publish streams when user not online. I know, a permission named "offline_access" for that, but I'm confused about that; do I have that I must store the access token key that I took while the user is online? Or are there any other method to using access token when user is offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API access tokens that taken with offline_access are long-lived tokens.(It's expires in 60 days). So yes, we must store access token key in our database but Facebook user must give access again in 60 days.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: I tried to use extended access token for offline access, but it's only work for 60 minutes.